# Checking whether ansible_ssh_user is defined yields strange result

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I've updated my ansible installation to `ansible-6.2.0` and some of my playbook
stopped working because `ansible_ssh_user` is not defined.

OK, when I tried to do a `set_fact` only if it's not defined (other users in my
organization might be working with older versions of ansible) I realized that
the `when: ansible_ssh_user is not defined` syntax yields strange results. For
example in my failing playbook I have:

```yaml
    - name: what is ansible_ssh_user 1
      debug:
          var: ansible_ssh_user

    - name: what is ansible_ssh_user 2
      debug:
          var: ansible_ssh_user
      when: ansible_ssh_user is not defined

   - name: check some other variable
      debug:
          var: iusjujkd
      when: iusjujkd is not defined
```

and when I execute that playbook, I get this output:

```
TASK [what is ansible_ssh_user 1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/yanez/projects/deploy/mondas_deployment/pb_update_mondas_config.yml:93
ok: [somehost.com] => 
  ansible_ssh_user: 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''ansible_ssh_user'' is undefined'

TASK [what is ansible_ssh_user 2] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/yanez/projects/deploy/mondas_deployment/pb_update_mondas_config.yml:97
skipping: [somehost.com] => 

TASK [check some other variable] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/yanez/projects/deploy/mondas_deployment/pb_update_mondas_config.yml:102
ok: [somehost.com] => 
  iusjujkd: 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''iusjujkd'' is undefined'
```

Why is it that the first task says `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!` but when you check
for it, ansible thinks that it is defined. In the third task I get the expected
behaviour. Is `ansible_ssh_user` somehow special
in that regard? Or am I missing something really obvious here?

**edit**

My ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /home/yanez/projects/deploy/mondas_deployment/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/yanez/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/yanez/anaconda/py3/envs/ansible/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/yanez/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/yanez/anaconda/py3/envs/ansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 14 2022, 07:04:59) [GCC 10.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

**edit 2**:

here a minimal example:

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
inventory=inventories/hosts.yml
retry_files_enabled=False
stdout_callback = yaml
jinja2_native=True

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
control_path_dir = ~/.ansible/cp
control_path = %(directory)s/%%C
pipelining = True
```

**inventory**

```yaml
---

local:
    hosts:
        localhost:
    vars:
        vhost_server_name: localhost
        # here I have more variables
```

**playbook**

```yaml
---

- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  remote_user: "{{ remote_user|default( vhost_server_name.split('.')[0] ) }}"
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: what is ansible_ssh_user 1
      debug:
          var: ansible_ssh_user

    - name: what is ansible_ssh_user 2
      debug:
          var: ansible_ssh_user
      when: ansible_ssh_user is not defined

    - name: check some other variable
      debug:
          var: iusjujkd
      when: iusjujkd is not defined
```

**output**

```
$ ansible-playbook -i /tmp/inventory.yml --extra-vars "host=local" /tmp/strange.yml  -vv
ansible-playbook [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /home/yanez/projects/deploy/mondas_deployment/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/yanez/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/yanez/anaconda/py3/envs/ansible/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/yanez/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/yanez/anaconda/py3/envs/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 14 2022, 07:04:59) [GCC 10.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
Using /home/yanez/projects/deploy/mondas_deployment/ansible.cfg as config file
redirecting (type: callback) ansible.builtin.yaml to community.general.yaml
redirecting (type: callback) ansible.builtin.yaml to community.general.yaml
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: strange.yml *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in /tmp/strange.yml

PLAY [local] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [what is ansible_ssh_user 1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /tmp/strange.yml:8
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_ssh_user: 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''ansible_ssh_user'' is undefined'

TASK [what is ansible_ssh_user 2] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /tmp/strange.yml:12
skipping: [localhost] => 

TASK [check some other variable] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /tmp/strange.yml:17
ok: [localhost] => 
  iusjujkd: 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''iusjujkd'' is undefined'
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: _6.2.0_ is a meta package of pip, we won't get much information from this, what does `ansible --version` gives? BTW, I cannot reproduce on a _2.13.2_

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε hi, I've edited my question and added the output of `ansible --version`

Comment: @VladimirBotka I did't want to use the real hostname on which I was running the tasks and I replaced it with `somehost.com`. I forgot to do that in the third task, that's why it's not consistent, I fixed my question.

Comment: @VladimirBotka about the undefined question. Where does the message `''ansible_ssh_user'' is undefined`  come from? That's ansible's ouput. I executed the playbook like this: `ansible-playbook some_playbook.yml -vv`. Compare it to the output of the third task where I use a variable that's obviously not defined.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I've updated my question with a minimal example

Comment: @VladimirBotka I've added my `ansible.cfg` file

Comment: Oh I see, my `ansible_ssh_user` variable has now the value `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''ansible_ssh_user'' is undefined`. I don't understand where it is set with that value. I posted the files with which I created the second output and unless I'm very blind, I cannot find the place where `ansible_ssh_user` is set.

Comment: The issue might be closed if it is that trivial. I'm indifferent. The answer might help someone to debug *ssh* connection plugin. But, if you'd like to close it go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is trivial. The value of the variable *ansible_ssh_user* is the string

```
"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'ansible_ssh_user' is undefined"
```

---

**Debugging of a potential problem with the variables that control the connection plugins.**

I'm not able to reproduce the problem in Ansible 2.12. Given the tree and the **minimal** content

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── playbook.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
inventory = $PWD/hosts
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
[local]
localhost

[local:vars]
vhost_server_name=srv1.example.com
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: "{{ remote_user|default(vhost_server_name.split('.')[0]) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_ssh_user
    - debug:
        var: ansible_ssh_user
      when: ansible_ssh_user is not defined
    - debug:
        var: iusjujkd
      when: iusjujkd is not defined
```

The play works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e host=localhost playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_ssh_user: srv1

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  iusjujkd: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Notes**

- *remote_user*, *ansible_user*, and *ansible_ssh_user* refer to the same value. *remote_user* is a parameter. *ansible_user* and *ansible_ssh_user* are variables. See *ssh* connection plugin

```
shell> ansible-doc -t connection ssh
```

Quoting the parameter *remote_user*:

```
- remote_user
        User name with which to login to the remote server, normally set by the remote_user keyword.
        If no user is supplied, Ansible will let the SSH client binary choose the user as it normally.
        [Default: (null)]
        set_via:
          cli:
          - name: user
            option: --user
          env:
          - name: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER
          ini:
          - key: remote_user
            section: defaults
          vars:
          - name: ansible_user
          - name: ansible_ssh_user
```

---

- Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user, ansible_host, and ansible_port. See [Release notes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.0/CHANGELOG.md)

---

- See [Using connection plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#using-connection-plugins)

---

- Use FQDN to test the parsing

```ini
vhost_server_name=srv1.example.com
```

---

- Simplify the code by putting *ansible_user* into the inventory. Remove the variable from *hosts* and limit the hosts at the command line. (You have to put it into the extra var anyway).

```yaml
shell> cat hosts.yml
local:
  hosts:
    localhost:
  vars:
    vhost_server_name: srv1.example.com
    ansible_user: "{{ vhost_server_name.split('.')|first }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_user
    - debug:
        var: ansible_ssh_user
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml -l localhost playbook.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_user: srv1

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_ssh_user: srv1

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your tips. This collection of playbooks has a long history and I haven't had the time to go through all the playbooks and roles and update them, that's why it's still using old variables. I will consider them.